# How to draw a directed network graph with texts on both sides of edges in R (via iGraph, network or some other package)?

Tags: r, text, graph, label, igraph

How to draw a directed network graph with texts on both sides of edges in R (via iGraph, network or some other package)?

[image: directed network graph with texts on both sides of edges]

Variables (in vector autoregressive model (VAR)) are in nodes.

The Granger causalities (p values of the F statistics) are on both sides of edges. I put p values to the beginning of each arrow. I draw near-significant causalities with added emphasize.

I could not figure out how to get such a network diagram via iGraph or network package or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `edge.label` and `vertex.label` options together.

```
library(igraph)
el <- data.frame(sender = c("lnbist1f","lnbist1f","lnbist1f",
                            "kur1f","kur1f","kur1f",
                            "lnaltin","lnaltin","lnaltin",
                            "mfaiz1f","mfaiz1f","mfaiz1f"),
                 receiver = c("mfaiz1f","lnaltin","kur1f",
                              "lnbist1f","lnaltin","mfaiz1f",
                              "mfaiz1f","lnbist1f","kur1f",
                              "lnbist1f","lnaltin","kur1f"),
                 pval = c(0.5,0.6,0.1, #I just typed random p-vals here
                          0.45,0.88,0.24,
                          0.12,0.51,0.99,
                          0.001,0.056,0.123)
                 )
arrows = c(2,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,1,1)
el <- as.matrix(el)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(el[,1:2], directed = T)
coordinates <- matrix(c(4, 4, 1, 1, 4, -2,7,1), nrow = 4, byrow=TRUE)
plot(g, edge.label=el[,3], 
     vertex.shape="crectangle", 
     vertex.size=45,
     edge.arrow.mode=arrows,
     layout = coordinates)
```

The `edge.arrow.mode` lets you control the arrowheads.  You can move the edge labels around with `edge.label.y` and `edge.label.x` options.

[image: igraph plot]

Comment: Thanks, paqmo. That figure is just I want. Unfortunately, being a novice to graph construction, I could not obtain that figure. Could you please specify the g object in your code here: `plot(g, edge.label=el[,3], vertex.shape="crectangle", vertex.size=45, edge.arrow.mode=el[,4])`. In buffer, I have Carlos's g.

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER. Oops, g should be a graph object created from the edgelist--forgot to include that code. I've updated the answer to include that.

Comment: I completed the missing part in your g definition (`g <- graph_from_edgelist(el[,1:2], directed = `) as `g <- graph_from_edgelist(el[,1:2], directed=TRUE)`. Then I added before plot that `coordinates <- matrix(c(4, 4, 1, 1, 4, -2,7,1), nrow = 4, byrow=TRUE)`. And, in plot I added plot(....,layout = coordinates). This way I obtained your diamond shaped net diagram. Now, only arrow heads were missing even though I made "directed=TRUE" in g definition.

Comment: seems to be a problem with how the `edge.arrow.mode` option is reading the matrix. Assign the vector to an object and use that--it works for me.

Comment: Bingo, it worked with a minor edit. Please delete surplus comma in `el <- .....0.123),)` After your deletion, I will accept it as an answer. Otherwise, it gives the error: `Error in el[, 3] : subscript out of bounds`. Many many thanks. Good job indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [documentation on the igraph plot function](http://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.common.html) it seems that there is not a lot of options to manipulate edges labels but you can manipulate vertex labels with label.dist and label.degree for example.. 
You can do something like that:

```
g <- graph.empty(n = 3) 
g <- graph(c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3), directed = TRUE)
labels <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
coords <- matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), nrow = 3)
plot(g, layout = coords, vertex.label = labels, vertex.label.dist = 3.5, vertex.label.degree = c(-pi/4, pi/2, pi, -pi/2, 0, 3*pi/4))
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjYfl.png)

Comment: Thanks, really very helpful. Perhaps, basing on your code, the complete network graph in the figure may be obtained easily.

Comment: The above code exhaust vertex.label object for some other purpose. But then, how one can impose node names (i.e., kur1f, lnbist1f, lnaltin, mfaiz1f in the above)?!!